# jquery this.next validation

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with a small problem using jquery this.next functions.

I want to validate the  so that it gives out a message like empty field etc.

here's the html:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50px;"><input class="network" type="checkbox" name="netW[]" value="PC1" id="PC1" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 350px;"><span>PC1</span><br /><span class="networkRole">
        <div style="margin-left: 10px; color: red;">
            <input class="NRoles" type="checkbox" name="networkRoles[PC1][]" value="CE" />CE</div>
                <div style="margin-left: 20px; color: #000;"><div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 20px;" class="readwrite"><input type="checkbox" name="rw[PC1][CE][]" value="Read" class="checkRW" /><span style=\"margin-left: 10px;\">Read</span></div>
                <div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 20px;" class="readwrite"><input type="checkbox" name="rw[PC1][CE][]" value="Write" class="checkRW" /><span style=\"margin-left: 10px;\">Write</span></div>
                </div>
```

and here the jquery that's not working at the moment:

```
(".checkRW").click(function(){
alert ($(this).parent().next().children('.checkRW'));   
});
```

I'm kind of lost with those next(). etc.
Where I'm going wrong?

Br,
Toby

Comment: depends on what `this` refers to here? what I mean, just add each related code block, `this` could be any div or input or anything in your HTML, and we simply can't guess.

Comment: Hi, this should be this class="network"

Comment: The `this` would refer to the tag, in this case `input`, that has a class of `checkRW` and has been clicked on.  Javascript if very specific about Blocks `{}` of code and the `this` will always refer to the Block that it is in.

Comment: @user2023042 Content is upvoted when it is well thought out and and easily conveys an idea, clear examples are import.  If you want upvotes you should consider editing your question.  You can read more about this at http://stackoverflow.com/about. The real value of this site is that others with your question will read it and think "I have the same problem, how did they solve it." A clearer question also leads to better answers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `next()` only goes down in it's search.  You can use `prev()` to look back or upward.  Or in your case `siblings()` will look in both directions.

You may also want to add a `.val()` on the end of the statement so that the `alert` will have some human readable text.

So you might want to try:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children('.checkRW').val()
```

To test things out it is helpful to go into the developer view.  If you are on Firefox you can look at Firebug by right clicking on the page and selecting `Inspect Element with Firebug`.  Then go to the `Console` tab.  Type in your jQuery select statement in at the bottom of the Console and hit Enter.  This will display in the console what it selects.  In your case `this` will not work in the console because it would just point to jQuery(), so you would need to add an `id` attribute to your `input` fields and search based on those. With something like this:

```
$('#1').parent().siblings().children('.checkRW').val()
```

Here is a version of what you suggested that I used to test this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50px;">
        <input class="network" type="checkbox" name="netW[]" value="PC1" id="PC1" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 350px;">
        <span>PC1</span><br />
        <div class="networkRole">
            <div style="margin-left: 10px; color: red;">
                <input class="NRoles" type="checkbox" name="networkRoles[PC1][]" value="CE" />CE
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 20px; color: #000;">
                <div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 20px;" class="readwrite">
                    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="rw[PC1][CE][]" value="Read" class="checkRW" />
                    <span style="""margin-left: 10px;\">Read</span>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 20px;" class="readwrite">
                    <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="rw[PC1][CE][]" value="Write" class="checkRW" />
                    <span style="""margin-left: 10px;\">Write</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $(".checkRW").click(function(){
            alert ($(this).parent().siblings().children('.checkRW').val());   
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to traverse to the second `div` in that code, you only need one `parent()`, not two. The second `parent()` call will go one level higher.

Comment: Hi, edited the question should now be a bit easier to test it.